# Scripts are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have my code and it works when I simply run it in a browser (such as chrome) but what I am doing is making a chrome extension and chrome extensions do not allow the javascript to be embedded in the html but I need a way to add the javascript to the page. I can link a source of js like I have done in my code and this will work with the extension requirements that I need but I have a forum that I need to get the data from and I do not know how to do that without adding an onClick event inside the html tag. Here is my code

```
 document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = check(this.form);




/*function to check userid & password*/
 function check(form){
/*the following code checks whether the entered userid and password are 
matching*/
if(form.username.value == "SeeGreatness" && form.password.value == 
"SeeGreatness")
 {
window.open('https://www.google.com'); /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
}
else
{
alert("Error Password or Username");/*error*/
}
}
```

that is for the javascript it is in the same folder as everything else and its file name is login.js
next up I have some html and css (the css is not of any concern) its file name is login.html and here it is...(you may need to scroll)

```
   `<html>
   <head>
    <title>Login page</title>
   </head>
 <body>
   <h1 id="h1">simple login page</h1>

     <form id="login" name="login">
         <p>Username</p>
           <input type="text" name="username"/>

         <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <input id="submitButton" value="Login" type="button"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
  </form>
   <label>
   <script src="login.js"></script>
   <style src="login.css"></style>
   </label>
   </body>
   </html>`
```

so I'm just not sure how you send the information from the form to the js file for it to "verify" the password and username
(please note that this (as in the login page's security) is just for a concept and won't be published as that's very insecure)
thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = check(this.form);` you are calling the function right away, not binding an event handler.

Comment: so I should add that line after I declared the function?
i thought that javascript compiled the code before so that's not an issue?

Comment: you shouldn't invoke it..

Comment: How do I bind it then. I know you can bind it using DOM but I never learnt how to do it that way

Comment: Try binding a click listener to the button: `myElement.addEventListener("click", function(){ check(this.form); });`

Comment: So 
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", check(this.form));
no that does not work (unless I'm doing it wrong)

Comment: Check the console log to see if there are any errors. Perhaps `document.getElementById("submitButton")` is `null`.

Comment: good idea will do that right now

Comment: all i get is 
`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution`
on login.html:13

Comment: my new js code is quite literally https://pastebin.com/NvUxdQ9t

Comment: its not loading any js from that file i know why because they are in the same folder let me change that now it works XD (the js does now cuz i added a alert ) now to test it no it doesn't.. it doesn't recognize the click event ill check errors now i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (login.js:10)`

Comment: im confused by form.userid.value (i have changed userid to username and back before so if you are playing along then you will need to do the same then. the latest code is at https://pastebin.com/4iyKvQqB

Comment: i got it to work using `var userIdValue = document.getElementById("userid").value;
var passwordvalue = document.getElementById("password").value;`
and changeing `if(form.userid.value == "SeeGreatness" && form.password.value == "SeeGreatness")` to it

Comment: That's a good path, keep debugging and you'll find your solution.

Comment: thanks it seems to keep firing the click event on load tho so i am adding a true false to it to stop it from doing that i think its time to stop for the day tho and start up tomorrow

Comment: Remove form tag from the HTML: the browser doesn't have a built-in web server so submitting simply reloads the page, aborting any subsequent code. Or you can preventDefault on the submit event.

Comment: Most recent code is at https://pastebin.com/KCZLtcum

Comment: I rewrote everything out (doesn't have any verification code) but I did find something else that may or may not work so here is my code ...my as in my file not something I came up with XD this is way harder than I planned all I need is a html and js file that checks a text field for a specific string ... Password and username can be "SeeGreatness" I don't care lol but I cannot have an onclick in the html (I can however add it using the external js file) here is the code with the next file link at the end of the html file in a comment https://pastebin.com/yXRvhe5C

Comment: Most of the things some people have said to do confuse me such as what wOxxOm said I would only ask for example code (doesn't even have to be specific to work with my code as I would like to learn how to solve this issue rather than get someone else to fix it XD as I'm sure I'm going to need to know it again in the future.